# Allow closing a modal when clicking outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I used [bootstrap-modal plugin](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) for my project. But now I have an issue with closing my modal by clicking outside of it. I tried to pass the options like: `data-backdrop="true"`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas of what's going wrong?

**EDITED:**

My modal is in a partial (using Rails)

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="btn-group topbar header-buttons" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <%= link_to 'Add', '#addModal', { 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' } %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', '#', class: 'btn btn-default disabled' %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', '#deleteModal', { 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for (@change_office_address), remote: true, format: :json, html: { class: :contact_form } do |f| %>
          <div id="error_explanation" style='display:none;' class="bg-danger text-danger alert fade in alert-danger alert-dismissable errors">
            <ul>
              <% if @change_office_address.errors.any? %>
                <% @change_office_address.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control' %>

          <br>
          <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'e-mail', class: 'form-control' %> <br>
          <%= f.label :city_id %>
          <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.order(:name), :id, :name,
                                  { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
          <br>
          <%= f.label :insurer_id %>
          <%= f.collection_select :insurer_id, Insurer.order(:short_name), :id, :short_name,
                                  { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
          <br>
          <%= f.label :office_id %>
          <%= f.collection_select :office_id, Office.order(:name), :id, :name,
                                  { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
          <br>
          <%= f.text_area :edit_office_address, placeholder: 'New address', class: 'form-control', cols: '30',
                          rows: '5' %> <br>
          <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.submit, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I call a modal by: `<%= link_to 'Edit', '#editModal', {'data-toggle' => 'modal'} %>`

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Check your logs. Bootstrap should have that behavior by default.

Comment: Why not use bootstrap modal directly? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I don't use it, cause I had some problems with links in modal to other modals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added this code, and now it's working:

```
$("#myModal").click(function(ev){
    if(ev.target != this) return;
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Backdrop option is **true** by default.

Check: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Make sure if you're call jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js correctly.

To test, press the Esc key and see if the modal is closed. By default, the keyboard option is also **true**.

If backdrop and keyboard doesn't working, there is a great chance you've called the .js wrongly.

Remember: call jquery.js **BEFORE** bootstrap.js.

If necessary, comment your console log here.

Finally, remember that Bootstrap does not support multiple modals.

Comment: Keyboard works correctly. The problem only in a backdrop